# Spinner y EditText

Tags: java, android

Tengo este código para cargar un spinner con datos de una base de datos:

```
private class Getfrutas extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Spinner.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Obtencion de las seccion..");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            ServiceHandler jsonParser = new ServiceHandler();
            String json = jsonParser.makeServiceCall(URL_LISTA_FRUTA, ServiceHandler.GET);
            Log.e("Response: ", "> " + json);
            if (json != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);
                    if (jsonObj != null) {
                        JSONArray seccion = jsonObj
                                .getJSONArray("frutas");

                        for (int i = 0; i < seccion.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject catObj = (JSONObject) seccion.get(i);
                            Seccion cat = new Seccion(catObj.getInt("id_seccion"),
                                    catObj.getString("seccion"));

                            frutasList.add(cat);
                        }
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("JSON Data", "¿No ha recibido ningún dato desde el servidor!");
            }
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();
            populateSpinner();
        }
    }


    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                               long id) {
        Toast.makeText(
                getApplicationContext(),
                parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString() + " Seleccionada" ,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        String seccion = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        k.setText(seccion);


    }
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    }
```

Como pueden ver estoy capturando el dato llamado sección, algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que necesito es que en el campo de texto se muestre el ID del dato seleccionado en el spinner, ¿alguna idea de como lo puedo hacer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Por lo que veo en tu codigo, usas la lista `frutasList` para llenar el spinner.
Rapidamente para responder tu pregunta de poner el id del elemento seleccionado en el edittext, se haria de esta manera

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    k.setText(frutasList.get(position).id); // <-- asumiendo que la clase Seccion tiene un atributo "id" y es tipo String
}
```

segun la posicion seleccionada del spinner, seleccionas el objeto en la lista `frutasList` y obtienes el atributo id del objeto Seccion

Comment: Gracias por el código, el problema es que en la clase Sección el id es Int, en ese caso, que podría hacer?

Comment: Ya lo resolví gracias

Comment: Lo que hice fue, nombrar una nueva variable String en la clase Sección, la iguale a la variable "id" pasándola de entero a una cadena usando "String.valueOf". Gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: Algo como esto `k.setText(String.valueOf(frutasList.get(position).id));`

Comment: Sí, algo muy similar